# Facebook not updating cache

Tags: facebook, caching, hyperlink

The problem is the Facebook lint tool get the correct values, but when I press *like*, I get an old description. I've waited 48 hours, cleared the cache with `&fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING`, and nothing seems to help.

Here's the link:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=falkenbergsrevyn.se%2FBloggdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D34%26fbrefresh%3DCAN_BE_ANYTHING

Press "skicka" here and see the problem:

http://falkenbergsrevyn.se/Bloggdetails.aspx?id=34

The values are correct in the lint but not when you "like" the post.

(I'm having problems with Facebook not updating their cache. I checked out the other posts about this, but nothing solved this..)

Comment: fix the errors strip html from your og:description and add : og:title, og:url, og:type, og:image and fb:admins or fb:app_id

Comment: "&fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING" - what is this?  What cache are you clearing?

Comment: frederick, I have the title and image tags to, Ive got it working on another page on the site without trouble. Actually, I didnt realise what i should change the fbrefresh to, and the author of the comment didnt state it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `og` meta tags are not correct.

```
<meta name="og:title" content="...
```

should be adjusted to the specification stated at http://ogp.me,

```
<meta property="og:title" content="...
```

Comment: I set the tags dynamically in code, and i cannot chosse to set them as meta property. also, the developing environment says it wrong and it still works on anaother page on the site with "name".